# Unity - C# - attach GameObject to public Button CommunicationButton;

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception, gameobject

I cannot solve this problem, I hope someone knows how to do this.

**What I have**

A button and a text field on a canvas, see image:

[image]

I have a script called HumanInstructions, that initializes like this:

```
public Text CommunicationMessage;
public Button CommunicationButton;
```

Right now I can assign the corresponding GameObject in the inspector, by choosing the button/textfield in a dropdown menu.

**What I want,** is choosing the GameObject through script. The textfield is called CrazyMsg and the button is called CommunicationButton. So I want something like this:

```
public override void OnAwake ()
{
    CommunicationMessage = GameObject.find("CrazyMsg");
    CommunicationButton = GameObject.find("CommunicationButton");
}
```

It doesn't work. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `GameObject.Find` not `GameObject.find`. You also need to get Component after finding the GameObject.

```
public Text CommunicationMessage;
public Button CommunicationButton;

void Start()
{
    CommunicationMessage = GameObject.Find("CrazyMsg").GetComponent<Text>();
    CommunicationButton = GameObject.Find("CommunicationButton").GetComponent<Button>();

    //Register Button Click
     CommunicationButton.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonClickCallBack());
}

//Will be called when CommunicationButton Button is clicked!
void buttonClickCallBack()
{
   CommunicationMessage.text = ....
}
```

You can also regsiter Button with `CommunicationButton.onClick.AddListener(delegate { buttonClickCallBack(); });` or `CommunicationButton.onClick.AddListener(buttonClickCallBack);`